# Manipulating Android Devices from a JavaFX app through ADB

Tags: java, android, api, javafx, adb

I'm trying to build an application in JavaFX that can control android devices through ADB for basic actions such as installing APKs, listing connected ADB devices, displaying devices' infos and so.

I have done most of UI design with JavaFX.
I need a way to start ADB server. Should I have a folder from where the app will start it? Does Java have support for ADB with API?

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no API for adb. So, you need to manually construct the command for **adb** and execute it then waiting for the result from it. You can use something like this:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = runtime.exec("adb -s ", null);

BufferedReader brInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader brError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

// you need to handle the reader.
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try your suggestion

Comment: @esQmo_: you can learn from https://github.com/appdictive/ADBWiFiConnect/blob/master/ADBWiFiConnectGUI/src/main/java/dk/appdictive/adbwificonnect/ADBCommands.java

Comment: This one is about ADB over Wifi

Comment: It's using the same technique. There is no different using adb usb or WiFi.

Comment: @esQmo_: If my answer satisfy your question, please mark it as an accepted answer.